# Making discord bot. Getting Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Discord Bot'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im getting an error of Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Discord Bot' inside of my cmd running "node ." the full thing im getting is;

```
"node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Discord Bot'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)                                                                                           at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.3.0"
```

The code i have in "main.js" is;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '?';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } 
});

client.login('my magical token');
```

Inside of my commands for "ping.js" it is;

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
}
```

Any way to fix this? do i need to start over?

I tried reinstalling everything in my node_modules and other node stuff. I should be expecting my bot to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to run `node main.js` not `node .`.

`node .` runs what is mentioned inside your `package.json` as `main` if thats empty it tries to run `index.js` which you do not use.

Comment: i got someone else to fix it, yes! this was the issue pretty sure! nedded to edit ``package.json`` so yeah! thanks, how do i close a thread?

Comment: You accepted the answer that is considered closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `node main.js`. You didn't specify which file is the entry point.